# Timestamp based on keyword within an array

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, timestamp, keyword-argument

I would like to make a function that will create a timestamp whenever a particular keyword is mentioned in a specified array. For example, if the array included the word "Item 1" in a cell, create a timestamp when it was populated in the sheet. Then if the next last line contains the word "Item 2" in a cell, create a timestamp when is was populated in the sheet. I assume I will need an if statement or for loop to perform the function. A portion of my script is below as reference:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Dewar ID');
var last_dewar = sheet4.getRange('A3:A50').getValues();
var last_entry = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Comment: How is the script supposed to know when the word was created in the row?  The only way I can think of doing this is using `onEdit(e)`.  When the user enters "Item 1" is will append a time stamp to the row.

Answer (score 0):

Is keyword in array?

```
function isKeywordInArray(keyword) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const array = sh.getDataRange().getValues().flat();
  if(~array.indexOf(keyword) {
    sh.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());//you pick the range
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the keyword is in the array that I Identified as const. How can I make a timestamp for it.

Comment: How about `sh.getRange().setValue(new Date());`

Comment: This was not working either. Am I not meant to to use a IF statement to preform them function? For example `if(array = keyword) sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(new Date());`

Comment: [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You if statement is not using a conditional operator it's using an assignment.  = is not the same as ==